# What exactly does -march=native do?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, gcc4

[Gentoo Wiki](http://web.archive.org/web/20130429073047/http://en.gentoo-wiki.com/wiki/Safe_Cflags/Intel) told me the following:

> Warning: GCC 4.2 and above support
> -march=native. -march=native applies additional settings beyond -march,
> specific to your CPU. Unless you have
> a specific reason not to (e.g. distcc
> cross-compiling), you should probably
> be using -march=native, rather than
> anything listed below.

What are those additional settings?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to see which flags -march=native will activate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5470257/how-to-see-which-flags-march-native-will-activate)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Nevermind.

```
$ cc -march=core2 -E -v - </dev/null 2>&1 | grep cc1
 /[...]/cc1 -E -quiet -v -iprefix /[...]/4.3.2/ - -march=core2

$ cc -march=native -E -v - </dev/null 2>&1 | grep cc1
 /[...]/cc1 -E -quiet -v -iprefix /[...]/4.3.2/ - -march=core2 -mcx16 -msahf --param l1-cache-size=32 --param l1-cache-line-size=64 -mtune=core2
```

I'm starting to like this option a lot. `-mcx16` and `-msahf` are two additional CPU instructions gcc can now use, which weren't available in earlier Core2's.

Comment: On my i7, it also adds `-mpopcnt -msse4.2 --param l2-cache-size=8192` where POPCNT is a rather neat CPU instruction.

Comment: Weird.  Do you ship the build machine along with your software?

Comment: @hans: lol, but the OP is working with Gentoo.  Which means no one distributes binaries, only code to be compiled on the machine on which it will be run.