# How to see which flags -march=native will activate?

Tags: gcc, g++, compiler-optimization, compiler-flags

I'm compiling my C++ app using GCC 4.3. Instead of manually selecting the optimization flags I'm using `-march=native`, which in theory should add all optimization flags applicable to the hardware I'm compiling on. But how can I check which flags is it actually using?

Answer (score 184, accepted):

You can use the `-Q --help=target` options:

```
gcc -march=native -Q --help=target ...
```

The `-v` option may also be of use.

You can see the documentation on the `--help` option [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.3.5/gcc/Overall-Options.html#Overall-Options).

Comment: I'm going to suggest that this is suboptimal. The output of --help=target doesn't display CPU cache information, of which the methods both elias and 42n4 below have listed. Specifically, on gcc 4.9.2 on a Phenom, the output includes these: ``--param l1-cache-size=64 --param l1-cache-line-size=64 --param l2-cache-size=512``

Comment: @DanielSantos: on my system it does display those parameters with the `-v` option, albeit as part of the `cc1` command line...

Comment: not perfect. on gcc version 5.4.0 (Buildroot 2017.05-rc2-00016-gc7eaf50-dirty) it will cause the error in return: Assembler messages:
Error: unknown architecture native
Error: unrecognized option -march=native.
So, loose the `-march=native` and it will work everywhere just following: `gcc -Q --help=target`.

Comment: @Oleg - That sounds like a bug in GCC 5. The issue is not present in GCC 7.

Answer (score 162):

To see command-line flags, use:

```
gcc -march=native -E -v - </dev/null 2>&1 | grep cc1
```

If you want to see the compiler/precompiler defines set by certain parameters, do this:

```
echo | gcc -dM -E - -march=native
```

Comment: This answer deserves as many upvotes as the accepted one for, in particular, listing what `native` really equates to.

Comment: so if i'd like to cross-native-compile, i should feed both the compiler both the defines AND the arguments? or is the arguments sufficient?

Comment: Pretty sure that the arguments are sufficient.

Answer (score 29):

It should be (`-###` is similar to `-v`):

```
echo | gcc -### -E - -march=native
```

To show the "real" native flags for gcc.

You can make them appear more "clearly" with a command:

```
gcc -### -E - -march=native 2>&1 | sed -r '/cc1/!d;s/(")|(^.* - )//g'
```

and you can get rid of flags with -mno-* with:

```
gcc -### -E - -march=native 2>&1 | sed -r '/cc1/!d;s/(")|(^.* - )|( -mno-[^\ ]+)//g'
```

Answer (score 15):

If you want to find out how to set-up a non-native cross compile, I found this useful:

On the target machine,

```
% gcc -march=native -Q --help=target | grep march
-march=                               core-avx-i
```

Then use this on the build machine:

```
% gcc -march=core-avx-i ...
```

Comment: This will not include all the flags unfortunately.

Comment: @BaptisteWicht are there flags that -march=native will include that -march=core-avx-i would not, in this case, or which flags? Thanks!

Comment: @rogerdpack On this computer (sandybridge), march=sandybridge does not enable AVX (don't know why) while march=native does. Another important difference is that cache sizes are only extracted with march=native

Comment: @BaptisteWicht that's odd seems to work here (I guess): `echo | gcc-6 -dM -E - -march=sandybridge | grep AVX #define __AVX__ 1` but cache sizes do seem absent.

Answer (score 8):

I'm going to throw my two cents into this question and suggest a slightly more verbose extension of elias's answer. As of gcc 4.6, running of `gcc -march=native -v -E - < /dev/null` emits an increasing amount of spam in the form of superfluous `-mno-*` flags. The following will strip these:

```
gcc -march=native -v -E - < /dev/null 2>&1 | grep cc1 | perl -pe 's/ -mno-\S+//g; s/^.* - //g;'
```

However, I have only verified the correctness of this on two different CPUs (an Intel Core2 and AMD Phenom), so I suggest also running the following script to be sure that all of these `-mno-*` flags can be safely stripped.

**2021 EDIT:** There are indeed machines where `-march=native` uses a particular `-march` value, but *must* disable some implied ISAs (Instruction Set Architecture) with `-mno-*`.

```
#!/bin/bash

gcc_cmd="gcc"

# Optionally supply path to gcc as first argument
if (($#)); then
    gcc_cmd="$1"
fi

with_mno=$(
    "${gcc_cmd}" -march=native -mtune=native -v -E - < /dev/null 2>&1 |
    grep cc1 |
    perl -pe 's/^.* - //g;'
)
without_mno=$(echo "${with_mno}" | perl -pe 's/ -mno-\S+//g;')

"${gcc_cmd}" ${with_mno}    -dM -E - < /dev/null > /tmp/gcctest.a.$$
"${gcc_cmd}" ${without_mno} -dM -E - < /dev/null > /tmp/gcctest.b.$$

if diff -u /tmp/gcctest.{a,b}.$$; then
    echo "Safe to strip -mno-* options."
else
    echo
    echo "WARNING! Some -mno-* options are needed!"
    exit 1
fi

rm /tmp/gcctest.{a,b}.$$
```

I haven't found a difference between `gcc -march=native -v -E - < /dev/null` and `gcc -march=native -### -E - < /dev/null` other than some parameters being quoted -- and parameters that contain no special characters, so I'm not sure under what circumstances this makes any real difference.

Finally, note that `--march=native` was introduced in gcc 4.2, prior to which it is just an unrecognized argument.

Comment: Nice, this gleans has the cache sizes as well

Comment: gcc version 5.4.0 (Buildroot 2017.05-rc2-00016-gc7eaf50-dirty)

returns: Error: unknown architecture `native'

Comment: Oleg: What arch are you using?  It could be that "native" is only supported on some architectures.

Answer (score 1):

There is [resolve-march-native](https://github.com/hartwork/resolve-march-native) for exactly this: It parses GCC output and combines the output from multiple calls to GCC into the eventual answer. For example:

```
# resolve-march-native --vertical
-march=sandybridge
-maes
--param=l1-cache-line-size=64
--param=l1-cache-size=32
--param=l2-cache-size=3072
```

There is also [distccflags](https://github.com/daniel-santos/distccflags) but it [seems discontinued](https://github.com/daniel-santos/distccflags/issues/7).

PS: I am the author of resolve-march-native.