# how to compile mono source code

Tags: c#, linux, gcc, mono, centos

I'm trying to compile source code of `Mono 3.2.5` with `centos 5.10`.
following gain error.

```
../../mono/utils/atomic.h:56: more undefined references to '__sync_val_compare_and_swap_4' follow collect2: id returned 1 exit status
make[3]: [pedump] error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory '/tmp/mono-3.2.5/mono/metadata'
make[2]: 
[all-recursive] Error 1
```

Comment: i am using gcc 4.1.2.
i will install mono 3.0
thank

Answer (score 1):

Please do it as it should be done.
A little search / and / or checking, what the code completion tells You, would have revealed this:
[undefined reference to `__sync_val_compare_and_swap_4' error at compilation, using gcc 4.1.1 and 4.2.0 for Sparc v8 target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329020/undefined-reference-to-sync-val-compare-and-swap-4-error-at-compilation-usi)