# Understanding dependencies of Rust libraries

Tags: rust, llvm

I'm writing for education purposes an embedded Rust program for ARM.
Since it is a bare metal system, I use the core library only. The library's manual page claims that corelib depends on nothing, but `memcpy`, `memcmp`, and `memset`, and the unwind functions (see https://doc.rust-lang.org/core/index.html).
However, especially if I use [atomic types](https://doc.rust-lang.org/core/sync/atomic/), I continue to get linker errors because of missing symbols, such as `__sync_val_compare_and_swap_4` or `__sync_lock_test_and_set_4` that indicates a missing [compiler-rt](https://compiler-rt.llvm.org) library.   I understand, that compiler-rt should on top of corelib. That looks like a circular dependency, what shouldn't be. In addition, I understand that compiler-rt in turn depends on an OS.

1. What part of my understanding is not correct?
2. How can I get a real independent corelib, or what parts of it are really independent? I know that I could re-implement the missing functions, but they seem to be quite a lot. Also, I'm aware of the [compiler-builtins crate](https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/compiler-builtins), but it still leaves me with unresolved symbols.

Comment: `__sync_val_compare_and_swap_4` is *not* provided by compiler-rt. Does linking to `libgcc_s` work? (ref http://stackoverflow.com/a/9329139/224671)

Comment: @kennytm: Not yet, I'm not sure whether I even have it for the target platform, but I'll give it a try. However, it is kind of strange that llvm should need libgcc_s.

Comment: The linked question uses GCC 4, I don't know what is the LLVM equivalent :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the meantime, I've found a solution. I share it in the hope it will be useful for somebody else.

As kennytm correctly mentioned, the symbols do not belong to compiler_rt. In addition, the symbols are only by chance the same as in the functions of the libgcc, c.f. [here](http://llvm.org/docs/Atomics.html#libcalls-atomic). The calls will be emitted by llvm in case the CPU does not support atomic commands such as `cmpxchg`.

My processor is an ARMv6 and *does* support atomic commands. However, I failed to tell Rust/llvm about: the JSON file with the target description looked like that:

```
{  "llvm-target": "arm-none-eabihf",  
   "target-endian": "little",
   "target-pointer-width": "32", 
   "os": "none",
   "env": "eabihf", 
   "vendor": "unknown",
   "arch": "arm", 
   "linker": "arm-none-eabi-gcc",
   "linker-flavor": "gnu",
   "data-layout": "e-m:e-p:32:32-i64:64-v128:64:128-a:0:32-n32-S64",
   "executables": true,
   "relocation-model": "static",
   "no-compiler-rt": true
}
```

In this way, my CPU could also have been an ARMv5 what do not support atomic commands. By adding a field `"cpu": "arm1176jzf-s"` I could solve the linker error.