# GCC won't use SSE in 32bit

Tags: gcc, sse, gcc4.8

On linux x64 if I compile code with gcc in this way

`gcc -m32 -march=native -mfpmath=sse -c -ftree-vectorize myfile.c`

if I give a look at the assembly I don't see any SSE istruction or register used, and the code result **exactly the same** the code generated without any flag  `gcc myfile.c`

In my code do many operations with array and matrices of floating point so It's pretty strange that gcc doesn't use SSE and doesn't perform any optimization in comparison with the base compilation.

Why? Is this a bug of the compiler?

EDIT

if I add the flag `-msse2` the compiler use also SSE instructions, but `march=native` should include all instruction supported by the current CPU therefore also SSE2. Why happens this?

Comment: You might want to try adding `-msse2`.

Comment: If I use march=native is not enabled?

Comment: I don't know - I just thought it would be worth trying.

Comment: What happens if you compile with optimization such as `-O3`?

Comment: @Z boson same thing doesn't use SSE. Only if as suggested Paul R iI add -msse2 seems use SSE despite all other flags that I have added

Comment: What version of GCC is it? I think it was fixed long ago, like in  GCC 4.4.something.

Comment: is gcc 4.8 as I have tagged

Comment: lol, looks like another case of, "nobody cares about performance on 32-bit".

Comment: This makes no sense.  What does [gcc -march=native -Q --help=target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5470257/how-to-see-which-flags-march-native-will-activate) show?  With `-m32` on my system it shows SSE2 enabled.  What is specifically your CPU?

Comment: Yes, It's absurd, help target shows that are enabled but aren't used if I dont explicit `-msse2`. Could depent by the fact I'm on a virtual machine?

Comment: `-march=native` tends to behave badly on some virtual machines, because those may advertise themselves as impossible machines (like a 64-bit pentium 2). However, if it says sse2 is enabled, I don't really see how -msse2 can make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Works for me with gcc 4.9.2.  (Ubuntu amd64)

```
// fp-simple.c
double fp_func (double a, double b)
{
        return a*b + 32;
}
```

`gcc -m32 -march=native   -ftree-vectorize  -S -o-`:

```
    blah blah a lot of mov insns because we didn't use -O3
    fldl    -8(%ebp)
    fmull   -16(%ebp)
    fldl    .LC0
    faddp   %st, %st(1)
    leave
    ret
```

`gcc -m32 -march=native -mfpmath=sse  -ftree-vectorize  -S -o- fp-simple.c`:

```
    mov ... copy from args to locals on the stack
    vmovsd  -8(%ebp), %xmm0
    vmulsd  -16(%ebp), %xmm0, %xmm1
    vmovsd  .LC0, %xmm0
    vaddsd  %xmm0, %xmm1, %xmm0
    vmovsd  %xmm0, -24(%ebp)
    fldl    -24(%ebp)
    leave
    ret
```

(with `-march=nehalem`, you get the same code, but non-VEX versions of the SSE instructions.)

So if gcc4.8 didn't behave like this, it sounds like a bug.