# What flags does -march=native activate with Clang?

Tags: clang, compiler-optimization, compiler-flags

[With GCC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5470257/how-to-see-which-flags-march-native-will-activate) one is able to print out the specific flags that `-march=native` triggers. Is it possible to have Clang print similar information?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Instead of using the (non-existent in clang) `-help=target` flag, you can use `echo | clang -E - -march=native -###` to print out the compilation command. While this doesn't list the non-triggered flags and it's not pretty, it does list all the enabled flags.